# How to get back my btc coins?

Tags: cross-chain-recovery

I have accidently sent my btc coins from my coinbase account to ETN coin address in cryptopia instead of btc coin address. Confirmation is seen in bitcoin account. How can i get it back?

Comment: Have you contacted cryptopia support?

Answer (score 0):

Contact the exchange you sent it to. They hold your private keys. I don't know if any other way. But they can either broadcast a transaction to send them back to your original wallet. Or give you the private keys and you'd be able to do it yourself. Either have them do it or get the keys. But do it quickly as days go by the harder it is for them to pull your keys. Some exchanges place them in cold storage. Bittrex along with other exchanges do not share keys and will not attempt recovery if it's under a certain dollar figure. Your best bet is contacting them